# Remove elements from an integer range

Tags: go, data-structures

I would like to remove a list of numbers from a `list of range of numbers`.

```
splitPoints := []int{22, 23, 24, 360, 500, 5500} // this is a sorted array
sortedArray := []int{1, 2-7, 9-100, 200-5500} // this is a sorted array
```

```
answer = []int{1, 2-7, 9-21, 25-100, 200-359, 361-499, 501-5499}
```

The range in `sortedArray` are of type `intRange`

```golang
type intRange struct {
    start int
    end   int
}
```

There's an `in` function on `intRange`

`func (s intRange) in(i int) bool {`

to check whether `i` belongs to the `intRange` or not.

I have two approaches to solve this. One involving recursion and the other without it.

However I am unable to write the working code for it.

### Update

#### Approach 1

```golang
func (s *intRange) split(i int) []intRange {
    result := []intRange{}
    // when only one element in the set and 'i' is the same element
    // return an empty range
    if s.start == s.end {
        return result
    } else
    // if 'i' is starting or ending element, remove that from the
    // current range and return the range
    if s.start == i {
        s.start = s.start + 1
        result = append(result, *s)
    } else if s.end == i {
        s.end = s.end - 1
        result = append(result, *s)
    } else {
        // When the element lies in between the range, split the range
        leftRange := intRange{
            start: s.start,
            end:   i - 1,
        }
        rightRange := intRange{
            start: i + 1,
            end:   s.end,
        }
        result = append(result, leftRange)
        result = append(result, rightRange)
    }
    return result
}

.... [SNIP] ....
func main(){
    splitPoints := []int{22, 23, 24, 3689} // this is a sorted array
    sortedArray := []int{1, 2-7, 9-5500} // this is a sorted array
    finalRange, tempRange := []intRange{}, []intRange{}
    counter, breakCount := 0, 0
    for _, splitPoint := range splitPoints {
        if len(finalRange) == 0 {
            tempRange = sortedArray
        } else {
            tempRange = finalRange
        }
        for ; counter < len(tempRange); counter++ {
            log.Debugf("[Loop]counter : %v\ttempRange : %s\n", counter, tempRange)
            s := tempRange[counter]
            if s.in(splitPoint) {
                sets := s.split(splitPoint)
                log.Debugf("Breaking...")
                if breakCount > 0 {
                    finalRange = finalRange[:len(finalRange)-1]
                }
                log.Debugf("finalRange : %s\n", finalRange)
                finalRange = append(finalRange, sets...)
                log.Debugf("counter : %v\tsets: %s\tfinalRange : %s\n", counter, sets, finalRange)
                // Increasing counter since, breaking doesn't increase the counter
                counter++
                breakCount++
                // when there's split break the loop and start from next iteration
                break
            } else {
                finalRange = append(finalRange, s)
            }
        }
        log.Debugf("counter : %v\tfinalRange : %s\n", counter, finalRange)
    }
    log.Infof("Final split range : %s", finalSet)
}
```

The output :

```
[Loop]counter : 0       tempRange : [1 2-7 9-5500]
[Loop]counter : 1       tempRange : [1 2-7 9-5500]
[Loop]counter : 2       tempRange : [1 2-7 9-5500]
Breaking...finalRange : [1 2-7]
counter : 2     sets: [9-21 23-5500]    finalRange : [1 2-7 9-21 23-5500]
counter : 3     finalRange : [1 2-7 9-21 23-5500]
[Loop]counter : 3       tempRange : [1 2-7 9-21 23-5500]
Breaking...finalRange : [1 2-7 9-21]
counter : 3     sets: [24-5500] finalRange : [1 2-7 9-21 24-5500]
counter : 4     finalRange : [1 2-7 9-21 24-5500]
counter : 4     finalRange : [1 2-7 9-21 24-5500]
counter : 4     finalRange : [1 2-7 9-21 24-5500]
Final split range : [1 2-7 9-21 24-5500]
```

The answer should've been :

```golang
[1 2-7 9-21 25-3688, 3690-5500]
```

Comment: What have you tried? Include your code. What problems did you encounter?

Comment: show how your answer and inputs related, and what you got so far

Comment: Hey added the code snippet and output

Comment: was it intended https://play.golang.org/p/yGgaV8499wI ?

Answer (score 0):

I have worked on it and got a solution like this. Inputs are `[]intRange` and `[]int` and output is again `[]intRange`.

I got this `[]int{1, 2-7, 9-100, 200-5500}` as string array `[]string{"1", "2-7", "9-100", "200-5500"}` and converted it into a `[]intSet` for my solution.

```
//set and points should be sorted
func split(set []intSet, points []int) []intSet {
    newSet := make([]intSet, 0)
    splited := make(map[string][]int)
    for _, s := range set {
        for _, point := range points {
            if s.in(point) {
                splited[s.String()] = append(splited[s.String()], point)
            }
        }

        p, ok := splited[s.String()]
        if ok {
            for i, pp := range p {
                if i == 0 {
                    if pp-1 >= s.start {
                        newSet = append(
                            newSet,
                            intSet{
                                start: s.start,
                                end:   pp - 1,
                            })
                    }
                    continue
                }
                if i == len(p)-1 {
                    if pp+1 <= s.end {
                        newSet = append(newSet, intSet{
                            start: p[len(p)-1] + 1,
                            end:   s.end,
                        })
                    }
                }

                tmp := intSet{
                    start: p[i-1] + 1,
                    end:   pp - 1,
                }
                fmt.Println(tmp)
                if tmp.start <= tmp.end {
                    newSet = append(newSet, tmp)
                }

            }
            continue
        }

        newSet = append(newSet, s)
    }

    return newSet
}
```

run on [playground](https://play.golang.org/p/ZiT3t0Gw0Hf)

Comment: you could reduce size of points along the iteration of `set`. Once we know we found a range containing `21 22 23` in the split points slice `[]int{22, 23, 24, 3689}` we adjust points to become `[]int{3689}` so that next iteration has less to work with.

Comment: this `splited := make(map[string][]int)` could be a simple `splited := make([]int)` that we reset at each iteration and this `p, ok := splited[s.String()]` could become `if len(p)>0`. If i understood correctly the algorithm

Comment: we can improve a little more this iteration `for _, point := range points {` by breaking once we know that further points are out of range. but anyways this are suggestions to apply after some good testing ; )

Comment: Yes sure,  @mh-cbon. Appreciate your comments and suggestions